# Horizontal Scrollbars on a Fluid Listbox

Tags: silverlight, listbox, datatemplate, scrollbars

**What I want:** To get the darn horizontal scrollbar to appear.  I will be editing it a bit just so i fits the rest of the app's style scheme, but not too much.

**What I have**

Here is the code for the listbox as of now.  Everything runs perfectly except the scrollbars dont appear.  You might say... "well you dont have a scrollviewer anywhere", but I have tried inserting a scrollviewer in numerous places and still no luck.

**The Listbox Code:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemsdatatemplate}" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalListBoxTemplate}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TransparentListBox}" VerticalAlignment="Center" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

**The 'TransparentListBox'** (to shut-up the selected background color):

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentListBox" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="HoverBorderBackgroundBrush" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,25,0" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Border x:Name="SelectedBorderBackgroundBrush" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,25,0" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Horizontal List Box** (to make the listbox Horizontal, rather than standard vertical)

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalListBoxTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

**The Datatemplate** (to actually show the Items)

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="itemsdatatemplate">
        <local:ListItemControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

I have a feeling its going to be a simple addition, but Thanks in advance.

**Update**

It looks like the scrollbars now do appear with this:

```
    <Style x:Key="ScrollingListBox" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <ItemsPresenter></ItemsPresenter>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

But they do not function accordingly.  They feel... broken.  However, if one was to define a static width (say 300) of the grid, then the ScrollViewer acts perfectly.  Right now I have a completely fluid layout (meaning things stretch to fill), is this not acceptable for scrollviewers?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your own template, you have to define the ScrollViewer in there and use an ItemPresenter instead of a ContentPresenter.

```
<Style x:Key="TransparentListBox" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="HoverBorderBackgroundBrush" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,25,0" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <Border x:Name="SelectedBorderBackgroundBrush" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,0,25,0" Background="Transparent"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: this is to be included in a 'style' for the listbox, correct?  This does, in fact, show the scrollbar, but it's not linked to the listbox.  Its basically a scrollbar that is not scrollable, and doesn't have a nub to move back and forth.

Comment: I updated the example. The scrollviewer goes inside the ControlTemplate of the ListBox. Maybe just remove the HorizontalScrollBarVisibility property so that the ListBox controls it. The "nub" will appear when you have an overflow of content. You will have nothing to scroll if your content doesn't exceed the width of the scrollviewer.

Comment: That, actually, puts the scrollbars in each of the listbox's items, rather than 1 big scrollbar to control the listbox itself.  Notice the 'TargetType'.  It's targeting a ListBoxItem.  Thanks.

Comment: Oops. My fault. I copied the wrong one :D   You are right. It needs to be inside the ListBox.Template, not ListBoxItem.Template. I misread your code. My apologies.